# Have DateDiff Show Decimals

Tags: ms-access, datediff

I am using the `DateDiff` function, but I would like for it to give me 3 decimal places.  How should my query be altered to achieve such result?  -- I need this done via the query itself not a VBA function.

```
Date123: DateDiff('d', [startdate], [enddate])
```

Comment: DateDiff('d',StDt ,EnDt ) is only going to give you Integers.  Do you just want to display an Integer with 3 decimals?  If you want to get partial days, you'll have to do a calculation like DateDiff('h', StDt, EnDt)/24 or something.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I'll change it to hours then and play with getting a decimal that way.  Thank you for that insight!

Comment: @RashidAbib - Depending on how accurate you want to get, you can also use 'm' (minutes) or 's' (seconds) and just divide by the appropriate amount of minutes or seconds in a day.  This, of course, assumes you have a datetime field and not a date field, but if your backend data is Access that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

For a line that you can just put into a query, I'd use something like the following.

```
Format(DateDiff("s",[DateOne],[DateTwo])/60/60/24,"#.###")
```

Better practice would be to create a function in a module in your db like the following. Then call it through the query. The code is more maintainable, testable and understandable.

```
Public Function DateDiffInFractions(DateOne As Date, DateTwo As Date) As String
    Dim SecondsDiff As Double
    SecondsDiff = DateDiff("S", DateOne, DateTwo) / 24 / 60 / 60    'Days/hours/minutes/seconds
    DateDiffInFractions = Format(SecondsDiff, "0.000")              'Format to 3 Decimal points. Return string
End Function
```

Comment: You can see the followup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997084/time-calculation-type-mismatch)