# Time Calculation Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the **seconds** difference between two dates **to two decimal places**. However, I am getting an error 13, type mismatch whenever I execute the code. I have searched online and tried many variations, yet I am always ending up with a type mismatch. I'm not sure how to resolve this. Could someone please teach me how?

**INFO**: was originally using code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141318/have-datediff-show-decimals)

Here is the current code:

```
Sub Query()
    Dim Beginning As Date: Beginning = Now: Dim Duration As Double
    ... more code ...
    Duration = Round((Now- Beginning) * 60 * 60 * 24, 2)
End Sub
```

This is working, thank you BigBen! Also, thank you Siddarth Rout.

By the way, I changed to the timer like you mentioned, BigBen, and it's much better. :)

```
Sub Query()
    Dim Beginning As Single: Dim Ending As Single
    Beginning = Timer()
    ... more code ...
    Ending = Timer()
    Duration = Format(WorksheetFunction.Round(Ending - Beginning, 2), "#0.00")
End Sub
```

Excellent service, thanks again!

Kind Regards,
Joseph

Comment: `Format` returns a `Variant/String`. The linked answer needs fixed.

Comment: Also that function won't return the difference in seconds at all. The `/ 60 / 60 / 24` converts the result of `DateDiff` from seconds back into days...

Comment: Are you trying to use a timer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a timer - is that a specific object in Excel VBA? I'm trying to calculate how long it takes for a section of code to run.

Comment: Yes `Timer` is *much* better for what you want to do :-). Anyways, glad to help. What matters is that you got the answer you needed, even if it took a bit to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Format` returns a `Variant/String` and you can't assign that to a `Double`. The linked answer is incorrect.
2. The function currently is taking the result of `DateDiff` in *seconds* and converting it *back* to days by dividing. You'll need a different approach if you want fractions of a second; `DateDiff` can only return a difference in *whole* seconds.

Just take the difference between the two dates and *multiply* by 60 * 60 * 24. You can then round as necessary:

```
Public Function DifferenceInSeconds(ByVal EarlierDate As Date, ByVal LaterDate As Date) As Double
    DifferenceInSeconds = (LaterDate - EarlierDate) * 60 * 60 * 24
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you BigBen, I updated the code in the original post with your suggestion and posted the result. It is giving me an unexpected result. Thank you Siddarth Rout as well. I don't know how to incorporate your suggestion into workable code, I apologize.

Comment: @Joseph316: I believe you are using the dates in reverse :)

Comment: Ahh, you are right! Embarassing. Okay, I've fixed it, lol. However, I'm still not getting any decimal places - any idea why?

Comment: @Joseph316 - take off the rounding and look at the raw result :-)

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks, it turns out the resulting numbers were either #.99999993747 or #.00000023848. I guess the round functions drop the decimals when the number is so close to a whole number?

Comment: @Joseph316 - one thing to note, `Round` works differently than `WorksheetFunction.Round`. But those two numbers, rounded to 2 decimal places, are 1 and 0 respectively. For future reference, use `WorksheetFunction.Round` or `Application.Round`, not the `Round` function. [`Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function) uses bankers rounding, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the original post to use the `WorksheetFunction.Round`. I'm guessing that if I was adding together multiple rounded values, banker's rounding would result in a more accurate result, but since I'm only using one value, standard routing is better. Am I right in this assumption? I was reading [this page](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm) for information on the rounding.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do but my guess is just to stick with `WorksheetFunction.Round`. I've never needed bankers rounding.